# Group by LEFT(code, 4) and select one of the descriptions as 1

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query that provides me this current output:

**Data**

```
0001    Californian Whole Almonds (Own Label)       0.50
0001    Californian Whole Almonds                   1.00
0001    Californian Whole Almonds (Own Label)       1.00
0001    Californian Whole Almonds (Own Label)       3.00
0001    Californian Whole Almonds                   6.00
0001    Californian Whole Almonds (Own Label)       6.00
0001    Californian Whole Almonds                   10.00
0001    Californian Whole Almonds (Own Label)       10.00
0001    Californian Whole Almonds (HP)              1.92
0001    Californian Whole Almonds (HP - Own Label)  1.92
0001    Californian Whole Almonds (HP - Own Label)  1.50
0002    Flaked Almonds (Own Label)                  0.50
0002    Flaked Almonds                              1.00
0002    Flaked Almonds (Own Label)                  1.00
0002    Flaked Almonds (Own Label)                  3.00
0002    Flaked Almonds                              6.00
```

**Query**

```
SELECT LEFT(code, 4), description, w.WeightInKilograms AS WeightKG FROM Product p
JOIN TechnicalDatabase.dbo.Weights w on p.searchRef1 = w.Weight
```

**Question**

How can I `group` all the `LEFT(p.code, 4)` together, pick one of the descriptions that is same as `LEFT(p.code, 4)` and finally sum up the weight?

**What I tried**

**Current Output**

```
0001    Californian Whole Almonds                   17.00
0001    Californian Whole Almonds (HP - Own Label)  3.42
0001    Californian Whole Almonds (HP)              2.88
0001    Californian Whole Almonds (Own Label)       20.50
```

**Query tried**

```
SELECT LEFT(code, 4), description, SUM(w.WeightInKilograms) AS WeightKG FROM Product p
JOIN TechnicalDatabase.dbo.Weights w on p.searchRef1 = w.Weight GROUP BY LEFT(code, 4), description;
```

**What it should be:**

**From this**

```
0001    Californian Whole Almonds (Own Label)       0.50
0001    Californian Whole Almonds                   1.00
0001    Californian Whole Almonds (Own Label)       1.00
0001    Californian Whole Almonds (Own Label)       3.00
0001    Californian Whole Almonds                   6.00
0001    Californian Whole Almonds (Own Label)       6.00
0001    Californian Whole Almonds                   10.00
0001    Californian Whole Almonds (Own Label)       10.00
0001    Californian Whole Almonds (HP)              1.92
0001    Californian Whole Almonds (HP - Own Label)  1.92
0001    Californian Whole Almonds (HP - Own Label)  1.50
0002    Flaked Almonds (Own Label)                  0.50
0002    Flaked Almonds                              1.00
0002    Flaked Almonds (Own Label)                  1.00
0002    Flaked Almonds (Own Label)                  3.00
0002    Flaked Almonds                              6.00
```

**To this**

```
0001 Californian Whole Almonds (Own Label)  42.84
0002 Flaked Almonds (Own Label)             11.5
```

**Explanation**

I am grouping by specifically by `LEFT(p.code, 4)` and I am needing to select any of the descriptions as 1 and show the sum of the weight. Just not sure how to do this.

Comment: Can you display any description or does it have to be a particular one?

Comment: `MAX(description)` or `MIN(description)` and exclude `description` from `group by` clause?

Comment: @SBFrancies Any of the description will do, preferably that does not contain word `(Own Label)` or `HP - Own Label`. But that's something I can filter out.

Comment: Please paste your data in text format, because this way it can be reused for sample query in answers. Also, you can check this: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> pick one of the descriptions that is same as LEFT(p.code, 4) and
> finally sum up the weight?

You want one of the description then just use `MAX/MIN` on Description column and remove it from `GROUP BY` as follows:

```
SELECT LEFT(code, 4), 
       max(description) as description, 
       SUM(w.WeightInKilograms) AS WeightKG 
  FROM Product p
  JOIN TechnicalDatabase.dbo.Weights w on p.searchRef1 = w.Weight 
GROUP BY LEFT(code, 4);
```

Comment: This is perfect, I didn't think that `max/min` can also be used for strings.

Answer (score 0):

One option, using `ROW_NUMBER` with a random ordering to select a description:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY LEFT(code, 4) ORDER BY NEWID()) rn,
              SUM(w.WeightInKilograms) OVER (PARTITION BY LEFT(code, 4)) WeightKG
    FROM Product p
    INNER JOIN TechnicalDatabase.dbo.Weights w ON p.searchRef1 = w.Weight
)

SELECT LEFT(code, 4), description, WeightKG
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```